# Skype for Business Using Lync 2013 SDK- AutomationModalitySettings.FirstInstantMessage Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, lync-2013, skype-for-business

I have the following code used to start an IM conversation-

```
public void IMbtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var participants = new List<string>();
            participants.Add("blabla.com");

            if (_lyncAutomation != null)
            {

                var bridgeNames = _info.Bridges.Where(b => b.Selected && b.Enabled).Select(b => b.Name);
                var chatTitle = $"{_info.Title} {string.Join(", ", bridgeNames)}";
                string chat = "Welcome to test's chat!";

                AutomationModalities mode = AutomationModalities.InstantMessage; 
                var convoSettings = new Dictionary<AutomationModalitySettings, object>();
                convoSettings.Add(AutomationModalitySettings.Subject, chatTitle);
                convoSettings.Add(AutomationModalitySettings.FirstInstantMessage, chat);
                convoSettings.Add(AutomationModalitySettings.SendFirstInstantMessageImmediately, true);

                try
                {
                    _lyncAutomation.BeginStartConversation(mode, participants, convoSettings,
                                                      StartConversationCallback, null);

                }
                catch (LyncClientException lyncClientException)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Call failed.");
                    Logger.Log("Exception while creating Lync call: " + lyncClientException);
                }
                catch (SystemException systemException)
                {
                    if (IsLyncException(systemException))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Call failed.");
                        Logger.Log("Error: " + systemException);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The code creates an IM convo perfectly with the title and everything; however in my environment (using Skype for Business), the first message does not send, ALTHOUGH in a friend's environment using Lync 2013 he has no issues with the first message sending.

Has anyone heard of anything like this?

Thank you in advance for any assistance provided.

Comment: Have you yet figured this out @Brady? I am trying to start/send a simple `Hello` conversation., and have been looking/searching for a working code. Were you able to get the code above to work?

Comment: The sub you've written above, after I opened the solution file that came with where should I copy it to test/work in my App.xaml.cs file? Or MainWindow.Xaml.cs It's my first time writing C#. 

I am referring to the .sln file which we get from the sample conversation program we get after installing from here [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Lync-2013-Start-an-IM-27951440)

Comment: The above code should work. If you haven't already gotten it working you should place it in your MainWindow.Xaml.cs file and in your .xaml add a click event to a button similar to this- Click="IMbtn_Click"

Comment: Oh, the only thing is that this should be an e-mail address associated with a Skype account-

participants.Add("blabla.com");

should be 

participants.Add("blabla@blablabla.com");

Even if it's a fake e-mail address it should still work though, but it takes two fake participants to create a group chat I believe, so you would add it twice

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what would cause that issue but would an acceptable work around be to send the first message with the `StartConversationCallBack`